# How to draw shapes (ellipse) at a specific position?

Tags: photoshop, geometry, shapes, ellipse

Is there a simple way to draw shapes like ellipse or polygon at exact position in Photoshop? How to get circle (ellipse) centered at exact origin?

Comment: this doesn't appear to be on topic unless you want to do it via scripting.

Comment: Try pressing shift button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved in the following manner:

1) Enable the ruler by pressing (ctrl+R) or (cmd+R) 
2) Assuming you know the exact position of the center of the shape in pixels, change the measurement to pixels. Or any other unit.
3) Go under [View->New Guide] and place horizontal and vertical guides such that they intersect at the reqd co-ordinate.
4) Draw the shape anywhere.
5) Make sure the [View->Snap to->Guide] is checked On.
6) Go to free transform for that shape (Ctrl+t) and move it such that the center is near the intersection point and it'll automatically snap to it.
Done! :)

Comment: I did it in a similar way. I seems there is no better / quicker way to do that.